# Looking for a input template for Limit

Tags: front-end, formatting

I'm using v. 8. I'm looking for a limit input template (analogous to the integral template), but I can't seem to find it in any of the palettes. Can anyone help?

Edit: I'm looking for a 2D input (traditional form) purely for typesetting purposes (no calculations) Something analogous to the integral template (pictured below):

[image]

Comment: Typing `?Limit` will show you several.

Comment: @bills Yes, but I don't see a 2D input template among the choices.

Comment: What do you mean by 2D? The fancy typesetting one or a multidimensional one?

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes, good question. The fancy typesetting one.

Comment: Such a 2D, traditional form, input template would be very nice to have. You should write to `suggestions@wolfram.com` suggesting it be added to the Basic Math Assistant and Classroom Assistant palettes.

Comment: @murray Yes, good idea; I definitely will. I assume you will, too!

Comment: @murray And perhaps post on community.wolfram.com to make some noise.

Answer (score 3):

The **Basic Math Assistant** palette has a `Limit` template button:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which gets you something like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

EDIT: AFAIK you can only get a `TraditionalForm` wrapping rather than the functional template-style ones for `Integrate` or `Sum`. From the help:

```
Limit[f[x], x -> Subscript[x, 0]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Right, but I guess I should have clarified that I'm looking for 2D input.

Comment: @yroc something like this: `Limit[f[x], x -> 0] // TraditionalForm` or `Limit[Sin[x], x -> 0] // HoldForm // TraditionalForm`?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that one. Unfortunately that won't quite do it for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wasn't quite the right formatting (alas), but this gets an upvote just for being able to navigate to it in that palette.